# Using 'RefEdit' control to check specific range

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have a user form in which the user is asked to select a range of cells using a `RefEdit` control. I am trying to store the corresponding range in a range variable so I can run several checks on that range (no empty cells, valid inputs, ...). For now I've tried to do it using (as I've seen lots of people doing it that way on the Internet):

```
Dim Data_Range as Range
Set Data_Range = Range(RefEdit_DataRange.Value)
```

but it only ends with an error:

> 'Error 1004: Method "Range" for object "_Global" failed. (approximate translation)

I printed `RefEdit_DataRange.Value` in a MsgBox and it's a string formatted `Sheet!Cell1:Cell2` so it looks like what I was expecting but it's not working.

Did anyone ever run into that same issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to pass your sheet reference before the range address, from what you have, the `split` seems the easiest way to do it :

```
Dim Data_Range As Range, _
    A() As String

A = Split(RefEdit_DataRange.Value, "!")
Set Data_Range = Sheets(replace(A(0),Chr(39),"")).Range(A(1))
```

Comment: I have modified the script to split the reference into the sheet and cells reference but I now get "Error defined by the application or the object" and the Set Data_Range = Sheets(A(0)).Range(A(1)) line is highlighted

Comment: I got it now ! The error came from the reference format being R1C1. Unchecked it and now it works just fine.

Comment: Does A(0) an A(1) have the expected values? Does the sheet's name have a space in it? Because if there is you may have `'` around the name to wrap it and we'd need to get rid of these to make this work! Give the edit a try! ;)